# How to go from edges to connected components in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edges

I'm here because i'm a bit stuck and I cannot find a proper solution to my situation.
I have an input image. I used canny filter on this image to retrieve the edges:

```py
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("path/to/image.jpg")
canny = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 200)
```

[image: Example input image]

Now, from this edges, I want to labelised each connected components with a different color.
Obviously, I know there is such a function named `connectedComponents` from openCV or even scikit.
The problem is that these functions will label the contours of each edge! I want to label the interior delimated by the edges!

Now, I'm using this trick:

```py
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("path/to/image.jpg")
# eventually resize/downsample the image here so that the canny filter will work better
rs = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 200)
op = cv2.morphologyEx(255 - rs, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5, 5)))
op = cv2.erode(op, np.ones((2, 2)))
_, ccs = cv2.connectedComponents(op, connectivity=4)  # or connectivity=8
```

Then `ccs` looks like what I want, If I display it with `label2rgb`:

```py
from skimage.color import label2rgb
out = label2rgb(1 - ccs)  # or label2rgb(ccs)
cv2.imwrite("canny.jpg", (255 * out).astype(np.uint8))
```

[image]

The problem is that some of the components are labelised with the same color while they are not touching!

Do you know how to do what I want? On the internet everybody works with the contours. I want to labelized each area delimated by the contours!

Comment: Canny doesn’t produce complete contours, it only produces lines where there are edges. There is nothing forcing these to form closed contours. Therefore, these edges don’t separate regions in the image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how canny works. I know it doesn't separate regions in the image, but nothing can prevent me from using these edges as I want. Here, I want to use them as contours and, kind of, flood-fill each area delimited by these edges. Obviously I can do it with `flood_fill` algorithm, a set and a loop but it's not optimal. I can perhaps do it with find/union strategy but since I'm using python it will be quite slow. So I'm wondering if there are a function or a trick to do what I want but in a fast manner

Comment: “flood-fill each area delimited by these edges” But that is the problem. The edges don’t necessarily delimit areas. You need to do a lot of additional work to fill gaps and invent new edges where the contrast was too low to find any. This has been an active area of research for a long time, with no good results. Visual perception is rather hard to implement in a program. This is why Deep Learning is so popular nowadays, it solves the general object identification problem without having to solve this incomplete contours problem.

Comment: I know, the edges don't necessarily delimit area. But who cares? I got the output of my canny filter. Then, if I flood-fill from a black pixel. It will expand until it touches somes edges (according to the connectivity the threshold parameters and so on). Obviously some of the edges can be inside my area but I don't care as long as I could retrieve my area. I need to do that for each area. As you mentioned deep-learning. The idea is actually to refine a segmentation that I got from my deep neural network :).

Comment: Who cares? Apparently you do! "some of the components are labelised with the same color while they are not touching!" This is because those components are not completely separated by edges, thus they form a single connected component.

Comment: Your code isn't producing any contours at all, so how can you expect to label the area bounded by a contour? You would use `findContours()` to find contours in a binary image, not `Canny()`